# How to select camera in Camorama?

Tags: webcam

I have two webcams connected: `dev/video0` is the laptop built in webcam and `dev/video1` is an HD quality webcam that I would like to use, but Camorama defaults to `dev/video0`. How can I select `dev/video1`?

Comment: I can do it with this is a terminal: camorama --device /dev/video1

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following command from the shell:

```
camorama -d=/dev/video1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible in Camorama.

Use "Cheese" instead of "Camorama" and simply select the camera you need in preferences.

Comment: Are you saying that's impossible to do using Camorama?